# .Net : Parse html containing variables

Tags: html, .net, xml, parsing

I have this html containing fields, if and foreach with this syntax:

```
<% if ( obj.DayPeriod == "Morning" ){ %>
<h1>Good Morning.</h1>
<% if ( obj.User.Name == "Eric" ){ %>
<div>Welcome back Eric</div>
<div>You have <%= obj.User.ChildrenNumber %> children.</div>
<% } %>
<% } %>
<% } else { %>
<h1>Good Afternoon.</h1>
<% } %>
```

It can also contains foreach like this:

```
<% for each (var c in obj.User.Children) { %>
<tr>... <td>... <%= c.@name %>...
<% } %>
```

I also have a xml feed with the structure that we can see in the code sample above:

```
<obj>
   <DayPeriod>Morning</DayPeriod>
   <User>
       <Name>Eric</Name>
       <ChildrenNumber>2</ChildrenNumber>
       <Children>
       ....
       </ChildrenNumber>
   </User>
</obj>
```

Do you have any idea how I could parse and generate the html replacing the variables by what is contained in the xml? 
Precision : I cannot change the format and I am on the .Net platform.

The result here would be (of course, this is a simplified example and data is dynamic):

```
<h1>Good Morning.</h1>
<div>Welcome back Eric</div>
<div>You have 2 children.</div>
```

Comment: If the markup is being rendered with a view engine (it looks like normal view code, except for the `for each` syntax error, should be `foreach`), then I imagine all you need to do is deserialize the XML into an object and pass that object to that view engine.  Or, are you looking to *create* a view engine?  That is, are you looking to parse the actual *code* in that view and interpret it?  Because that's... not trivial.

Comment: Thx. I think I can change the "for each" by "foreach" just before the interpretation, it is not a problem. I don't use a view engine, the html is generated by a third party and I don't know what they use...

Comment: If you genuinely need to write your own language parser for this then maybe a good place to start would be the MVC Razor source code.  (Perhaps someone else has a better place to start.  I've never written a language parser but that's where I'd start for this.)  If there are any tutorials for writing a custom ASP.NET MVC view engine, that could be helpful.  Structurally, that's exactly what you're doing.  You have a "view" template and a "model" object and you want to bind them together.

Comment: Ideally, I would prefer to use an existing engine and modify the input only slightly but what engine could work?